# Complex valued function f is analytic in the annulus $0<| z |<1$, then f has antiderivative iff $Res_{z=0} f = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm thinking of the function $f=\frac{1}{z}$ but then stuck there. And still not sure what is the importance of the annulus $|z|<1$

Comment: Can you show that $f$ has an antideritvative iff $\int_{1/2}^z f(s)ds$ doesn't depend on the path of integration iff $\int_{|z|=1/2}f(s)ds=0$

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ has  an anti-derivative then the integral of $f$ over the circle of radius $\frac  1 2$ around $0$ is $0$. By Residue Theorem the residue of $f$ at $0$ must be $0$.

Conversely suppose the residue is $0$. Then $f$ has a  Laurent series expansion $f(z) =\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} a_nz^{n}$ and $a_1=0$. An anti-derivative of $f$ is $g(z)=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac  {a_n} {n+1} z^{n+1}$ where the term corresponding to $n=-1$ is interprted as $0$.